# How to make PyMOL draw bonds between atoms in console / script?

Tags: pymol

I want a PyMOL script to automatically draw bonds for a given structure, e.g. between all palladium atoms, or between all palladium and sulfur atoms.

I can do this manually by the `bond` command, but need to know the identifiers of the atoms:

```
bond id 3, id 4
bond id 2, id 6
...
```

- How can I create all the desired bonds at once?
- It would also be helpful, if a bond is created only, if the distance between the atoms is within a specific cutoff radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After crawling the [PyMol mailinglist](http://sourceforge.net/p/pymol/mailman/pymol-users/), I managed to connect all atoms. e.g.

```
bond (elem pd), (elem pd)
```

draws [bonds](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Bond) between all the Pd atoms.

---

Now to the cuttoff radius:

```
bond (elem pd), (elem s) within 2.5 of (elem pd)
```

draws bonds between **all Pd atoms** and **all S atoms within the range of 2.5 of any Pd** atom. This is resulting in a weired structure with very long bonds.

<strike>I think it's necessary to [iterate](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Iterate) over one of both selections to yield bonds within the desired cutoff radius only.</strike>

Instead, I make use of the [find_pairs](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Find_pairs) function of pymol (this is API only and thus has to be used in a [python script](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Simple_Scripting)).

```
from pymol import cmd, stored

pd_s_bonds = cmd.find_pairs('n. pd', 'n. s', cutoff=2.5)
for pair in pd_s_bonds:
    cmd.bond('index %s' % pair[0][6], 'index %s' % pair[1][7])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem.

If you append indices to the names, you can use following syntax:

```
(elem P) within 2.5 of (name Ru1)
(elem P) within 2.5 of (name Ru2)
```